# How does Ruby's OptionParser work?

Tags: ruby, optionparser

"Minimal example" of OptionParser from http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV
```

Main questions:

- What exactly is the content of `opts` there? Is it the new OptionParser instance, or is it all of the `/-\w/` or `/--\w+/`-looking things passed to the script? As a corollary, is that `do` block a loop or not?
- What does `parse!` do? Why is it called on the whole `do` block?

Also wondering:

- What is the `OptionParser#banner` method? In what context would you see that text?
- In what context would you see the third parameter passed to OptionParser in that example, that little description of the flag's effect?
- How can you create a custom error message if the script is run with an unknown option?

Comment: Your question is too broad. On Stack Overflow a question is supposed to be a *single* question, or occasionally two closely related questions, but beyond that is frowned upon; You have nine. Restricting questions is to help avoid confusion and diluting the usefulness of the pages. You will find answers to your OptionParser questions in the documentation you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

1. `opts` is just the new instance of `OptionParser`. The block supplied to `.new` is run with this line:

   ```
   yield self if block_given?
   ```
2. `parse!` is the same thing as `parse` but it is *destructive*, meaning that it will remove used switches from `ARGV`. It is called on the entire `do ... end` block because the value returned is the new `OptionParser` instance.
3. `banner` gets the heading of the summary, which can be set with `opts.banner = "foo"`
4. The description is shown when the help is displayed (`-h` flag):

   ```
   Usage: example.rb [options]
       -v, --[no-]verbose               Run verbosely
   ```
5. You could rescue the `OptionParser::InvalidOption` exception:

   ```
   parser = OptionParser.new ...

   begin
     parser.parse!
   rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption
     puts 'Invalid args!'
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, August!

Comment: I'm still unclear on what `parse` actually does though -- the documentation doesn't explain.